# Does unity3D optimize floats at any point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering if anyone knew off the top of their head if unity does any optimization under the hood with floats.

Because their `mathf` function which essentially wraps the C# `math` function, presumably because it used floats instead of decimals, which in itself is a kind of optimization, but they're still twice the resources as a `ulong` which can be used to store the values and then divided by factors of ten.

When making physics calculations that are dealing with hundreds to thousands of floats per frame, it just seems like we'd want all the opt we could get.

Optimally I'm told I'd want to use pointers, which I will provide a link to, but I'm not sold on running in *unsafe.*

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/804103/how-to-enable-unsafe-and-use-pointers.html

Comment: I don't know if it actually is wrapping the C# math function. They do their own native implementations in the mono CLR for a lot of stuff and I would not be surprised if `MathF` is one of them.

Comment: Also, did you profile your code and saw that the `MathF` functions actually where where the code was spending most of it's time or are you just assuming that is where it is spending the most time because it is the most logical choice?

Comment: Does it use float over decimal? U sure? Not double? Why would a ulong be an optimisation if it requires a multiplication for storage and a division to retrieve the value? Why would think pointer would be faster? For passing around the value? Still a 4 byte data. And then you still need to place the value on the register to perform the action. You may be in a case of trying to find a problem to a solution you are thinking of.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I have not checked the profiler yet, I wasn't asking because I was having performance issues I was just asking because a friend and I were talking about it. It was merely an assumption based on the fact ulongs are 64bits and floats are 128.

Comment: @Everts - It definitely uses a float over a decimal if you try to use Math.Abs it returns a decimal whereas the Mathf.Abs returns a float and in-fact gives you a compiler error if you try to use decimals. That being said, the point of pointers -are to be faster- in the sense. Pointers are basically a way to write code that directly references memory blocks, rather than having instructions to destroy and allocate new memory for the variables it needs to process. I'm not sure yet if it will in-fact be faster that would depend on how many floats could be converted to ulongs.

Comment: @ThomasCaplan floats are 32 bits, doubles are 64 bits, and decimals are 128 bit. So a `ulong` are twice the size of `float`, the same size as a `double` and half the size of a `decimal`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, wait until Vorspire hears about this. Thank you sir, my apologies for being an idiot or if you feel I wasted your time <3

Comment: Don't edit your question like that with a answer. Post an actual answer explaining what you learned and mark it accepted or delete the question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte (8-bit), Short (16-bit), Int (32-bit), Long (64-bit) and Decimal (128-bit) are accurate while Float (32-bit) and Double (64-bit) are not. The advantage of floating point are that they have a high range, but it comes at the cost of precision.

You get high accuracy close to zero and less at higher numbers. Tests I made with Unity for my own project showed I in some cases was unable to position things within my 1 meter grid already after 16 000, it would skip 1 meter.

Most graphics cards and their API uses 32-bit float datatypes. This is a trade-off between memory (and some, but not much, processing power) and precision. Therefore it makes sense that Unity also use float. Although some commercial cards have started getting [support for 16-bit and 64-bit floating points](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10510/nvidia-announces-nvidia-titan-x-video-card-1200-available-august-2nd).

Unity makes no optimizations on the float itself, it hands it over to the GPU in most cases in a raw state. That is the most optimized way of doing it.

The choice of wrapping Math in Mathf is probably to avoid confusion (i.e. of method signatures) and to allow them to extend the Math class properly.

Example of one of the bigger drawbacks: My game has a near infinite world and therefore has to have a "[Futurama Engine](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_matter_engine)". It adjusts the player to 0,0,0 and the world accordingly every now and then to prevent any objects from being at too high/low positions in float. "*The engines don't move the ship at all. The ship stays where it is and the engines move the universe around it.*" If Unity and the graphics cards used Decimal this would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:**

> Floats are 32 bits, doubles are 64 bits, and decimals are 128 bit. So a ulong are twice the size of float, the same size as a double and half the size of a decimal.

```
-Scott Chamberlain
```